# Read txt file from specific of line to a certain line base on string

Tags: python, string

I am trying to write some function of data, however, my data is like this:

```
noms sommets
0000 Abbesses
0001 Alexandre Dumas
0002 Paris
0004 Nice
...
coord sommets
0000 308 536
0001 472 386
0002 193 404
```

What I want to is to access from `nom sommets` to `0004 Nice` without knowing the number of line but base on the string value of txt

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "base on the string value of txt".  If you want to read until the line `0004 Nice` but don't want to know the line number, then you must want to read until the line you read contains `Nice`.  So why not just do that?  Why not read lines until you find one that is some number followed by `Nice`?

Comment: because, this is just sample, what happend if I want to read from '0002 Paris' to '0001 472 386' without knowing the number of line

Comment: If you don't know the number of the line, what is it that you do know that would cause you to stop reading?  Without worrying about your code, and just looking at the file, what is it that would cause you to know when to start and stop reading?

Comment: this is why I am trying to figure it out, how to start and stop the reading

Comment: But, is there a way to get a number of the line of '0002 Paris' and '0001 472 386' so we can do it in normal way

Comment: before new set starts will this line apperas `...` ? everytime

Comment: '...' mean there is a lot of data behind it

Comment: Got it..Check solution @Beam291

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read text file to list split based on key word `sommets`

```
with open('text.txt') as file:
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in file]

test_loop = []
for item in lines:
    if 'sommets' in item: 
        test_loop.append([item])
    else:  
        test_loop[-1].append(item)
print(test_loop)
```

which gives `list of lists` #.

```
[['noms sommets', '0000 Abbesses', '0001 Alexandre Dumas', '0002 Paris', '0004 Nice', '...'], ['coord sommets', '0000 308 536', '0001 472 386', '0002 193 404']]
```

If you want to access first set then.

```
for sublist in test_loop[0]:
    print(sublist)
```

Gives #

```
noms sommets
0000 Abbesses
0001 Alexandre Dumas
0002 Paris
0004 Nice
...
```

Answer (score 0):

we can read the whole txt file as single string then use regex to match the keyword.

`re.DOTALL` modifier will make '.' match any character including newline

```
with open('text.txt') as f:
  txt = f.read()

match = re.search('noms sommets.*?0004 Nice', a, re.DOTALL).group()
# match = 'noms sommets\n0000 Abbesses\n0001 Alexandre Dumas\n0002 Paris\n0004 Nice'
```

then, you can use match as variable or split it into list

```
>>> print(match)
noms sommets
0000 Abbesses
0001 Alexandre Dumas
0002 Paris
0004 Nice
>>>
```